# iOS - Persistent wi-fi timing out after 30mins when Cellular connection is active

Tags: ios, ios6, wifi, core-audio, nsstream

The app I am working on needs wifi to be constantly on as I sends/receives audio using wifi network. It then plays out the audio. The needs to do this continuously until the user chooses to stop it.

**The problem:**
iOS turns off WiFi after 30 mins, hence the sockets close and the AudioQueues stop. Here is an excerpt from Apple's documentation:

> To prevent the Wi-Fi hardware from using too much power, iOS has a
> built-in timer that turns off the hardware completely after 30 minutes
> if no running app has requested its use through the
> UIRequiresPersistentWiFi key. If the user launches an app that
> includes the key, iOS effectively disables the timer for the duration
> of the app’s life cycle. As soon as that app quits or is suspended,
> however, the system reenables the timer.
>
> **Note:** Note that even when
> UIRequiresPersistentWiFi has a value of true, it has no effect when
> the device is idle (that is, screen-locked). The app is considered
> inactive, and although it may function on some levels, it has no Wi-Fi
> connection.

**Things that are already implemented:**

1. The audiosession is activated on the device. It is kept that way until the user chooses to stop the audio or until the connection is lost and the AudioQueues are stopped too.
2. UIRequiresPersistentWiFi is set to true in the .plist file
3. Reachability APIs are implemented to detect any connection loss and do the needful.
4. "Application does not run in background" is set to "false" in the .plist file
5. "Required background modes" has the item "App plays audio" in the array in the .plist file.
6. NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoiceforKey is set on the property NSStreamNetworkServiceType for the sockets on both the devices.
7. The kCFStreamPropertyNoCellular property set on the sockets to a value of kCFBooleanTrue does not help
8. The only setting that helps is setting the NSStreamNetworkServiceType to NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP and adding the "App provides Voice over IP services" for the "Required Background modes" field in the .plist file. However Apple will reject the app for not implementing any VoIP services in the app.

I have been talking to Apple DTS about this issue, according to them there is no API level support to help with this problem. I however have my doubts about this claim, there are several apps(For example Pandora) on the app store that will need this feature.

Comment: Quite detailed question, but have you actually started an audio session ? Also make sure you are not at the area with over 500 wifi spots (if you know what I mean :), the connection would be unstable.

Comment: @A-Live, yes, that is mentioned in the first note above in the section "Things that are already implemented".

Comment: In case you need to open new network stream for AudioQueue, are you doing it with background task ?

Comment: @A-live, no, the network stream is not opened in a background task. The processing of data received on the stream is sent to a background task. Would it help if I did? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: From my experience a background task allows you to properly run the application until the new stream is opened and you have the packages to use at AudioQueue. When it happens, you can stop the task and let AudioSessionSetActive with `audio` background mode to keep the application alive. I believe it happens because there's a time interval with no actual playback. So I've wrapped `CFReadStreamOpen` with the task from `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` finishing it when AudioQueueBufferRef has enough data to start playing, no wifi problems as far as I remember.

Comment: `iOS has a built-in timer that turns off the hardware completely after 30 minutes if no running app has requested its use through the UIRequiresPersistentWiFi key` i think the key word here is `running`.. you mentioned several things about settings etc.. but you didn't mention how/when your threads are running and when they stop.. perhaps if you explain in a little more detail what your app does.. or why you need wifi to be on all the time? as in..>

Comment: <.. `The app I am working on needs wifi to be constantly on as I sends/receives audio using wifi network` so is this like one device communicating with a server constantly or two devices talking to each other? is it a p2p architecture or server client architecture etc.. such details would give us more room to address your question :)

Comment: @abbood, it is a p2p architecture, with 2 ios devices constantly taking to each other. 2 devices exchanging audio between each other. There is one thread that serves to sen/receive data from sockets. It is started when the socket created.  There is another thread that records/plays audio. It is started as soon as data is available to record or play audio.

Comment: @A-Live, I do not have any race condition issues with respect to the starting of the stream or delay in receiving data. The app always runs on local wi-fi, there is never any delay. Infact it always runs for exactly 30mins before the audio stops because the wifi is shutdown. Once the audio queue stops, there is nothing left to keep the app alive in background, hence it is backgrounded.

Comment: I should have tested it first, the behavior seems to be the same with my apps. If you have any other app that bypasses the limitation, I'll be glad to make sure that is true, unfortunately Pandora doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the device sleep timer and tell the user to keep the app in the foreground. This will prevent the display from turning off (screen locked), which will prevent the device from entering a lower power state, which will allow the WIFI radio to stay powered-up.

Comment: But why not just buffer enough to allow time to reconnect to the stream over cellular?

Comment: Expecting the app to be kept in the foreground is not the intended behavior for the app. Otherwise, that would have been probably been the easiest solution for the problem. Also the app is intended for use over local wi-fi network, and talk to devices within the local network.